Why does subscribing to new pending transactions also include very old pending?
My service is subscribing to new pending transactions on the memblock and process them accordingly. However it also get very old pending transactions and not just the newest - why is this and is there a way of filtering the old pending transactions away? For example it got this seven day old pending transaction today https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2bb5e868925f3a863efcf4c09932c892834753f20f4c4a9ead8730e9fc8073dc
with connect("ws://192.168.0.100:8546/") as ws1:
    ws1.send(json.dumps({ "id": 1, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newPendingTransactions"] }))
    ws1.recv()
    message = json.loads(ws1.recv())
    txnHash: HexStr = message['params']['result']
    txn = web3.eth.get_transaction(txnHash)
    processPendingTxn(txn)
    


I've deleted my answer because it was misleading as there seems to be no way to pass multiple params like newHeads and newPendingTransactions, so as to get the pending transactions from new blocks.

The problem may be due to the fact that the websocket subscription to "newPendingTransactions" does not guarantee that you will receive only new transactions. This is because websocket subscription can sometimes return old transactions that were already included in the block.
Here are some possible solutions for this problem:
Using filters instead of websocket subscription:
Instead of using websocket subscriptions, you can use Ethereum filters, which only allow you to track new transactions.
You can use web3.eth.filter() to create a filter on "pending" and only process new transactions that come into that filter. You need to set a filter, that's all.

Unfortunately web3.eth.filter('pending') also gets old pending transactions sometimes, for example today I got this eight day old pending transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x64e0542d490f93513cecacdba82e8817d45603d11d03387b5a68f50bc42d6cf4

The key point is that you must ensure that you are only processing new transactions and not reprocessing old ones.
You can use caching to keep track of transactions that you have already processed.
Before processing a new transaction, you can check whether it has already been processed previously.
Instead of relying on all transactions received through a websocket subscription being new, you can check the transaction time.
You can compare the transaction time with the current time to determine if the transaction is truly new.

I get what you mean with using a local cache to see what pending transactions I've already processed, but it does not help me figure out if a pending transaction is old if I've never seen it before - the next time I see it, yes, but not the first time I see it. Also, pending transactions have no transaction time attribute, transactions only get a transaction time once they're assigned to a block (i.e. the block time).

python
with connect("ws://192.168.0.100:8546/") as ws1:
ws1.send(json.dumps({ "id": 1, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newPendingTransactions"] }))
ws1.recv()
processed_txns = set()  # Next to store processed transactions

while True:
    message = json.loads(ws1.recv())
    txnHash: HexStr = message['params']['result']


Check if the transaction has already been processed
if txnHash in processed_txns:
continue
    txn = web3.eth.get_transaction(txnHash)
    processPendingTxn(txn)

Add the transaction hash to the set of processed ones
processed_txns.add(txnHash)
Here's how you can try it.

I dont see how your cache solution would help me the first time I see the old pending tranaction, the second time it comes in, yes, but not the first time I see it. Thanks for your effort though.

OK. When you manage to fix it, please share your solution with me, as I was wondering how this problem could be solved. I would appreciate your feedback.
